# Ruby : Split string on boundaries

Tags: ruby, regex

I have a string of arbitrary characters, some of which are digits. I would like to break the strings into fields consisting of digits and non-digits. For example, if my string has the value 'abc34d-f9', I would like to get an array

```
['abc','34','d-f','9']
```

I'm nearly there, using look-behind and look-ahead expressions:

```
s.split(/( (?<=\D)(?=\d) | (?<=\d)(?=\D) )/x)
```

This splits on transitions between boundaries digit->nondigit and vice versa. However, I also get empty elements, i.e. this would return

```
['abc','','34','','d-f','','9']
```

Of course it is trivial to filter out the nullstrings from the array. I just wonder: Why do I get them, and how can I do it better?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`string.scan`](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/scan) function to return an array of matched strings.

```
> 'abc34d-f9'.scan(/\D+|\d+/)
=> ["abc", "34", "d-f", "9"]
```

`\D+` matches one or more non-digit characters where `\d+` matches one or more digit characters.

Your regex also works fine if you remove the capturing group. Because capturing group would also return the delimiter(*boundary on which the input string was splitted*) to the final output.

```
> 'abc34d-f9'.split(/(?<=\D)(?=\d)|(?<=\d)(?=\D)/)
=> ["abc", "34", "d-f", "9"]
> 'abc34d-f9'.split(/ (?<=\D)(?=\d) | (?<=\d)(?=\D) /x)
=> ["abc", "34", "d-f", "9"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Though I prefer @AvinashRaj's solution, it's always fun (and <s>sometimes</s> often instructive) to try to find other ways:

```
str = 'abc34d-f9'

a = str.split(/(\d+)/)    #=> ["abc", "34", "d-f", "9"] 
a.shift if a.first.empty? #=> nil
a                         #=> ["abc", "34", "d-f", "9"] 

a = str.split(/(\D+)/)    #=> ["", "abc", "34", "d-f", "9"] 
a.shift if a.first.empty? #=> "" 
a                         #=> ["abc", "34", "d-f", "9"] 

str.each_char.chunk { |c| !!(c =~ /\d/) }.map { |_,a| a.join }
                          #=> ["abc", "34", "d-f", "9"] 

str[1..-1].each_char.with_object([str[0]]) { |c,a|
  ((c + a.last[0]) =~ /\d{2}|\D{2}/) ? a.last << c : a << c }
                          #=> ["abc", "34", "d-f", "9"] 

(Ruby 2.2)
str.each_char.slice_when { |a,b| (a+b) =~ /\d\D|\D\d/ }.map(&:join)
                          #=> ["abc", "34", "d-f", "9"]
```